# Maximum Number of Occupants crossing US/Canada Border

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, driving, automobiles

There was a question on the [maximum number of occupants in a vehicle in Oklahoma](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17837/how-many-passengers-allowed-in-a-car-in-oklahoma-usa).  Now I have an issue:

My wife will be driving to Canada with our friends the car she wants to drive is an SUV with 2 rows(2 in the front and a bench in the back).

I was wondering if seating 1 adult and 3 kids in the back will be an issue crossing the US-Canada border?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many passengers allowed in a car in Oklahoma, USA?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17837/how-many-passengers-allowed-in-a-car-in-oklahoma-usa)

Comment: @Doc Different country.  While close the road rules are different.

Comment: If you're driving from the US to Canada, then US rules apply in addition to Canadian rules - and the US rules will almost certainly say "no" in this case.

Comment: @Doc That is correct.  But I'm concerned about border crossing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is illegal to drive a vehicle in the US where each passenger does not have a seat belt (with very few exceptions) - http://www.nhtsa.gov/staticfiles/nti/pdf/811458.pdf‎

It is illegal to drive a vehicle in Canada where each passenger does not have a seat belt (with very few exceptions) - http://www.mto.gov.on.ca/english/safety/seatbelt.shtml

Your vehicle apparently has 3 seats belts in the back seat.

You are asking if it's going to be a problem to carry 4 passengers in the back seat.

The answer is fairly clearly, yes, this will be an issue crossing the border as you will be breaking the road rules on BOTH sides of the border.

Answer (score 4):

No problem provided the vehicle is within rated capacity and everyone is belted/safety-seated in.

The kids (if young) should have approved car seats (though if they're not obviously decrepit, anchored properly and of the proper type such as rearward-facing for infants I don't think anyone is going to check the stickers). Here are the rules for Ontario.

http://www.mto.gov.on.ca/english/faq/safety.shtml#seats

Comment: Have you *ever* come across an SUV that legally seats 4 people in the back row?  Of course this is going to be a problem!!!

Comment: @Doc I read that as "One adult + (three kids in the back)". If interpreted your way.. well my answer covers it 'cause there won't be four seat belts.